# How to create a countdown timer in Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I need to create a countdown timer, but I am kind of stuck, I am kind of new to Ionic, I am still learning. I want to know how to approach this problem. I checked Observable from rxjs, but I could not make it work somehow. Could you possibly give me suggestions?

Comment: Well, I believe this guide shows exactly what you want: http://www.codingandclimbing.co.uk/blog/ionic-2-simple-countdown-timer-25